# AWK merging the lines

Tags: awk

I have input file like below

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I need output like below

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
```

Meaning first two lines to be joined together and then the next three lines to be also joined together.

Comment: What’s the logic for combining the lines?

Comment: And what about the capitalization? your code does something different from your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A double awk appproach:

```
$ awk '{printf("%s",$0 (NR%5==0?ORS:":"))}' file1 |awk -F':' '{print $1,$2;print $3,$4,$5}'
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
```

Lines are first joined in groups of five,each line joined with `:` symbol.

Solution work even if lines contain more words

```
$ cat file2
this is line 1
this is line 2
this is line 3
this is line 4
this is line 5
this is line 6
this is line 7
this is line 8
this is line 9
this is line 10

$ awk '{printf("%s",$0 (NR%5==0?ORS:":"))}' file2 |awk -F':' '{print $1,$2;print $3,$4,$5}'
this is line 1 this is line 2
this is line 3 this is line 4 this is line 5
this is line 6 this is line 7
this is line 8 this is line 9 this is line 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I can also do the job with `paste`:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -s -d $' \n  \n'
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
$
```

bash was used by me here (for `$'\n'`). And `seq 10` was to reproduce your input:

```
$ seq 10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$
```

Comment: The point of the question is to read and combine lines from data inside a file - not to generate a litteral sequence 1 to 10. The real file can contain data from a to z, or words, or whatever.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou yes, my answer is about reading and combining arbitrary lines from a file according to the stated rule. You've not understood something. Check and apply my `paste` command to such a file :) (but my answer is bad because it doesn't use `awk`)

Comment: No, it does apply on fields (split by whitespaces) not lines.

Comment: @αғsнιη Oh, was I wrong? Would `paste` use the fields split by spaces instead of lines?.. No, probably, my command does the right thing; I've just tried an input with spaces: `{ echo 1 a; echo 2 b; echo 3 c; echo 4 d; echo 5 e; echo 6 f; } | paste -s -d$' \n  \n'` The output is OK.

Answer (score 2):

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { maxlines=2 ; lc=0 }

{ outputline=outputline " " $0; lc++ }

lc % maxlines == 0 {
  sub(/^ /,"",outputline); # strip unwanted leading space
  print outputline;

  outputline="";
  lc=0;
  maxlines = 5 - maxlines; # flip-flop: 5-2=3, 5-3=2
}
```

This alternates between joining & printing either 2 or 3 consecutive lines.

Output:

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
```

or with the original input data:

```
Unix Linux
Solaris AIX Sco
```

Alternatively, using an array.  `awk` doesn't have a `join()` function so we have to provide one.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { maxlines=2 ; lc=0 }

function join(sep,array,       i) {
  result=array[1];
  for (i=2;i<=length(array);i++) result = result sep array[i];
  return result
};

{ lines[++lc]=$0 }

lc % maxlines == 0 {
  print join(" ", lines);
  delete lines;

  lc=0;
  maxlines = 5-maxlines
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the job with below `awk`:

```
awk -v step=3 '{l=(!l)?l$0:l" "$0} ++seen==2 && step==3{print l;step++;l=seen=""}
    seen==3{print l;step--;l=seen=""}' infile
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4 5
6 7
8 9 10
```